# Evaluate variable inside directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way that the src will be evaluated inside the directives ? This is my snippet:

```
app.directive('loadTemplate', function ($templateCache,$compile) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              src: '@'
          },
          template:$templateCache.get("'{{src}}'")
      };
  });
```

Comment: PS:
In this way the templates is loaded before including into the body

Answer (score 0):

Use templateUrl and it can accept a function:

```
app.directive('loadTemplate', function ($templateCache,$compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            src: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return attrs.src;
        }
    };
});
```

In your html:

```
<loadTemplate src="xxx.html"></loadTemplate>
```

Comment: in your opinion, can this resolve the caching like what happens when i use ng-include ?

Comment: Don't know what kind of cache problem happens to you, can you create a plnkr or fiddle to make it more clear?

Comment: Although i haven't verify it, i think it should be no cache problem when you are using this way to achieve dynamic template for a directive.